# Asserting that equation f(x) = g(x) has one (or no) solutions can we use weak monotonic properties? Or both functions shall be strictly monotonic?

Tags: proof-verification, monotone-functions

My math book gives 2 rules:

**Rule 1:** If $f(x)$ is *increasing* and $g(x)$ is *decreasing* (or vice versa), then equation $f(x) = g(x)$ either has no solutions or has only one solution.

**Rule 2:** If on some interval (x=a..b) $y=f(x)$ has maximum value $A$ and $y=g(x)$ has a minimum value $A$ (same) then equation $f(x) = g(x)$ is equivalent to the system of 2 equations: $f(x)=A$ and $g(x)=A$.

Question 1: *for rule 1 what kind of [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) function is meant - strictly monotonic* (first derivative is never equal to zero) *or weakly monotone* (non-increasing/non-decreasing, meaning first derivative can be zero at one or several points).

I think that at least one function need to be strictly monotonic while the other is allowed to be weakly monotonic - its first derivative can be zero at multiple points. Or more presicely, for equation $f(x)- g(x) = 0$ to have only single (or none) solution function $y=f(x)-g(x)$ must be strictly monotonic (and it is achieved if at least one of them is strictly monotonic, the other can be strictly or weakly monotonic).

Question 2: *for rule 2 - it can be applied to any functions f(x) and g(x) an there is no special requirement* that either of them is monotonic (weakly or strictly) and there are no any other special requirements of any other nature.

Comment: You're right that for rule 1, at least one function must be strictly monotonic.

Comment: And you're also right about rule 2, this applies for any functions regardless of monotonicity or other conditions.